# Does Azure support IPv6 that's statically assigned?

Tags: networking, azure, ipv6, azure-networking

Seems like when checking the box for IPv6 when creating a load balancer, it gives me the option to use dynamic or static. However, if I pick static and click 'ok', it then gives me an error that static is not supported.

Why is this option there? How can I use IPv6 for my load balancer? I'd like to support both IP4/6

Answer (score 1):

For now, Azure **doesn't** support static IPv6 address. You may vote for your requirement in [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/4992369-support-ipv6-throughout-the-azure-platform), all of the feedback you share in this link will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams.